# Error creating bean with name 'myEmf' -- javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: myPersistenceUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jndi

I'm trying to inject the EntityManager in the DAO classes.

But I get this error during server initialization (WildFly 10.0.0).

> 18:35:57,318 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Context initialization failed:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'myEmf': Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   myPersistenceUnit -- service
>   jboss.naming.context.java.myPersistenceUnit   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by:
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: myPersistenceUnit -- service
>   jboss.naming.context.java.myPersistenceUnit   at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)  at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)   at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>     ... 22 more

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.project"></context:component-scan>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myEmf" jndi-name="myPersistenceUnit"/>

</beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/MyDS</jta-data-source>

      <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
      </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

    <task:annotation-driven />

</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file></welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    ...

}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `root-context.xml` the reference is wrong.

```
jndi-name="myPersistenceUnit"
```

The correct one is

```
jndi-name="java:/MyDS"
```

Your server knows the second one, not the first one.

Comment: Apostolos, when I changed the jndi-name, I solved the NameNotFoundException on server startup, but the entityManager was not injected in the UserDAO class, and then I got a NullPointerException.

Comment: you are missing the equivalent beans at your root-context. have a look here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html. I'm not sure if you need persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding the beans to the root-context.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```